# Why is the following list comprehension not working in Python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list called `row`:

```
row = ['1234', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]]
```

I want to change `row[1]`, so that few numbers get replaced with a time and the rest gets replaced with the string `'ABS'`. Something like this:

```
['1234', ['ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', '09:54:59', '09:55:18', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS', 'ABS']]
```

Here is my code:

```
for obj in row_objs:
    row[1] = [str(obj.punch.time()) if x==obj.punch.day else 'ABS' for x in row[1]]
```

But I keep getting ALL the numbers replaced by 'ABS' with the above code.

When I do this:

```
for obj in row_objs:
    row[1] = [str(obj.punch.time()) if x==obj.punch.day else x for x in row[1]]
```

The time is placed correctly but the other numbers are still there.

```
['1234', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, '09:54:59', '09:55:18', 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]]
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: I might not have had enough coffee yet but isn't the problem here that `row[1]` gets overwritten with each iteration of the `for` loop such that OP is only seeing the effect of the last iteration?

Comment: @timgeb That appears to be the problem. They just had their question updated.

Comment: @timgeb: those `for` loops were not there when I commented before. They are expecting each `for` iteration to not affect the next iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are **replacing** the list each iteration. The last `obj` in your `for` loop doesn't match any of the integers, so the **end result** is that you generated a list with only `'ABS'` strings. Your second loop works because you take the already-replaced values by re-using `x`; that can be the original integer, or the later `time()` replacement.

Don't use a `for` loop. Collect all your `obj.punch` values in a dictionary mapping the `day` attribute to the `str(...time())` result, then use a list comprehension to look up matches:

```
days = {obj.punch.day: str(obj.punch.time()) for obj in row_objs}
row[1] = [days.get(x, 'ABS') for x in row[1]]
```

Now you replace `row[1]` just once.

Answer (score 0):

```
for obj in row_objs:
    row[1] = [str(obj.punch.time()) if x == obj.punch.day else isinstance(x, int) and 'ABS' or x for x in row[1]]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.